# value of one alert can be prnted in annotation description of another alert in Alert manager

Tags: prometheus, alert, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have one alert "sc_pcd_g2version" listed in AlertManager. It returns value 25.

I am looking for a way to pull this value "25" and print it into the annotation description of another alert "sc_pcd_encryption_server" in Alert manager.

See in the alert sc_pcd_encryption_server you can see in Bold letter that i am looking for to be included. To use Current alert value we use `$labels.value` likewise how to pull value of another alert and print it in annotation description?

```yaml
name: sc_pcd_g2version
expr: sc_pcd_g2version > 0
for: 1m
labels:
  job: node
  severity: warning
annotations:
  message: Possibility of pcd g2version failure {{ $labels.instance }}.
  summary: pcd g2version Check failure


name: sc_pcd_encryption_server
expr: sc_pcd_encryption_server > 0
for: 1m
labels:
  job: node
  severity: warning
annotations:
  message: Possibility of **sc_pcd_g2version "25"** in encryption server failure {{ $labels.instance }}.
  summary: pcd encryption server Check failure
```

Comment: First, alerts aren't created by alertmanager, in your case I believe they are created by Prometheus. Second, [edit] you question and add rules used to create both alerts (as text!).

Comment: @markalex thanks for the comment. I have updated the query please let me know if any further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this is not possible.

But in your exact case you could utilize a little trick: use `sc_pcd_g2version > 0 and on(instance) sc_pcd_encryption_server > 0` instead of expression in your second alert.

That way when using `{{ $value }}`, you get value of `sc_pcd_g2version` and not `sc_pcd_encryption_server`.

Something like this:

```yaml
name: sc_pcd_encryption_server
expr: sc_pcd_g2version > 0 and on(instance) sc_pcd_encryption_server > 0
for: 1m
labels:
  job: node
  severity: warning
annotations:
  message: Possibility of {{ $value }} in encryption server failure {{ $labels.instance }}.
  summary: pcd encryption server Check failure
```

This is possible because you don't use labels of `sc_pcd_encryption_server`, other than `instance`, and they will be same for both metrics I believe.

Be sure to check that `instance` is enough to match to metrics. If not, add needed labels to `on` clause.